# FileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:) returns nil on macOS

Tags: foundation, findersync

I keep getting crash reports in Xcode for one of my macOS apps published on the App Store. Actually it's not the main app that crashes, but the embedded Finder Sync extension. The crash reports indicate that this source code line

```
static var appGroupSaveDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: identifier)!.appendingPathComponent("Library/Application Support/somedata")
```

crashes with error

```
Swift runtime failure: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value + 0 (<compiler-generated>:0)
```

That line is a static variable defined in a class that is included in the main app as well as the Finder extension.

The documentation reads

> In iOS, the value is nil when the group identifier is invalid. In macOS, a URL of the expected form is always returned, even if the app group is invalid

If the documentation says that the method call can never be `nil`, why am I getting this crash? Is it a bug or is the documentation wrong, or am I doing something wrong? And why does the Finder Sync extension crash and not the main app? I cannot reproduce this crash with the App Store app or within Xcode and Console shows no crash reports for the app on my Mac.